# Substituting value in column with existing factor in r

Tags: r

I have a dataset, where the column 'workclass' has the following values:

[image]

Now it seems to me that the value 'privat' is really the same as 'Private' and so I would like to change it accordingly

If I run the following command I get an error message because the factor is not defined.

```
    > adult$workclass[adult$workclass == 'privat'] <- 'Private'
    Warning message:
    In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, adult$workclass == "privat", value = c(7L,  :
    invalid factor level, NA generated
```

If I 'unfactor' the column and 'refactor' it again after the operation, I end up with two different factors for 'Private'.

```
    > adult$workclass <- as.character(adult$workclass)
    > adult$workclass[adult$workclass=='privat']  <- 'Private'
    > adult$workclass <- as.factor(adult$workclass)
    > summary(adult$workclass)
          Federal-gov         Local-gov      Never-worked           Private 
                  960              2093                 7             22686 
         Self-emp-inc  Self-emp-not-inc         State-gov       Without-pay 
                 1116              2541              1298                14 
              Private              NA's 
                   10              1836
```

How can I merge 'privat' and 'Private'?

Comment: With base, you could employ gsub: adult$workclass <- gsub("privat","Private", adult$workclass)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the output of `levels(adult$workclass)`? It seems like your "Private" level is not exactly equal to the string 'Private'.

When I run the following code, I get the desired result:

```
f <- data.frame(f=factor(c(
  rep("Federal-gov", 960),
  rep("Local-gov", 2093),
  rep("Never-worked", 7),
  rep("Private", 22686),
  rep("Self-emp-inc", 1116),
  rep("Self-emp-not-inc", 2541),
  rep("State-gov", 1298),
  rep("Without-pay", 14), 
  rep("privat", 10),
  rep("NA's", 1836)
)))

f$f[f$f=="privat"] <- "Private"
f <- droplevels(f)
table(f)
Federal-gov        Local-gov             NA's     Never-worked 
         960             2093             1836                7 
Private     Self-emp-inc Self-emp-not-inc        State-gov 
       22696             1116             2541             1298 
Without-pay 
          14
```

Comment: It is unfortunate how R is inconsistent with quoting strings when printing... Among other things which are unfortunate about R ;)

Comment: Yes indeed. When working with csv files and in doubt it is probably best to use the universal whitespace separator (sep="").

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
library(dplyr)
adult %>%
  mutate(workclass = recode_factor(workclass, privat = "Private"))
```